# Erlang. Asynchronous http request. How to know when connection is broken?

Tags: http, asynchronous, erlang

Making an asynchronous request to some server using the [`httpc`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html) HTTP client

```
httpc:request(get, {Url, []}, [], [{sync, false}, {stream,
self}])
```

where `Url` is the URL of the server. Data is received by
`handle_info/2` in `gen_server` that called `httpc:request/4` but I should get message when the connection is broken and there is no `stream_end` message. Using timeout is not feasible for me, because server response can take a long time.

Is it possible to get message about a broken connection in `handle_info/2`? If not, please suggest way to know when the connection is broken?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For more heavy-duty lifting of HTTP requests, use ibrowse:

https://github.com/cmullaparthi/ibrowse

It has many more knobs to twist and turn for requests and is more complete w.r.t. many things. If http/httpc doesn't solve your problem, it is worth investigating if going to ibrowse will.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have tried to use ibrowse before. But, it seems, something goes wrong.
I am writting client for twitter streaming API and when I use ibrowse I get nothing, for example - 
http://pastebin.com/fJNELWJE .  When I use erlang http client, all works. I.e. many messages is got.

Comment: when how can I get messages from twitter?..because I am sure they send it after connect.

Comment: It must be something at your end, because your example ran perfectly here with full output after a flush.

Comment: Adam: Did you get this sorted in the end, I am also trying to get this working but am getting the same issues.

Comment: Nowadays, using either `gun`, `hackney` or my favorite `fusco` is probably better.